# Combine data of objects in NSMutableArray with same key

Tags: ios, dictionary, nsmutablearray, key

I have the following NSMutableArray with keys 'id, value, name' and with 'id, animal' :

```
    <__NSArrayM 0x7a64f450>(
    {
        id = ccc;
        value = 11;
        name = "Greg";
    },
    {
        id = bbb;
        value = 2;
        name = "Dan";
    },
    {
        id = aaa;
        value = 23;
        name = "Mary";
    },
    {
        id = aaa;
        animal = "dog";
    },
    {
        id = ccc;
        animal = "cat";
    }

)
```

Is it possible to merge content by matching keys? So in the end I'd have:

```
        <__NSArrayM 0x7a64f450>(
        {
            id = ccc;
            value = 11;
            name = "Greg";
            animal = "cat"
        },
        {
            id = bbb;
            value = 2;
            name = "Dan";
        },
        {
            id = aaa;
            value = 23;
            name = "Mary";
            animal = "dog";
        }

    )
```

I'm looking to combine objects if keys match for id. All other keys should be merged together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A more elegant way to do this is to use *NSPredicate*. Use this code. *arrRecords* is where you are storing all records before merge.

```
NSString *strKey;  
NSPredicate *predicate;  
NSArray *tempArray;       

for(int i = 0; i < [arrRecords count]; i++) {
    strKey = [[arrRecords objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"id"];
    predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"id == %@",strKey];
    tempArray = [arrRecords filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
    if([tempArray count] > 1) {
       for(int j =0; j < [tempArray count]-1; j++) {
       [[arrRecords objectAtIndex:i] addEntriesFromDictionary:[tempArray objectAtIndex:j+1]];
       [arrRecords removeObject:[tempArray objectAtIndex:j+1]];  // You need to remove the record from super set otherwise this will get duplicated again.
            }
        }
    }
```

**EDIT** - Code for NSDictionary objects

```
NSMutableArray *newRecords = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; // Add this also before method body

 for(int i = 0; i < [arrRecords count]; i++) {  

     strKey = [[arrRecords objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"id"];  
     predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"id == %@",strKey];  
     tempArray = [arrRecords filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];  
     if([tempArray count] > 1) {  
         NSMutableDictionary *tempDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];   
         for(int j =0; j < [tempArray count]; j++) {  
             [tempDict addEntriesFromDictionary:[tempArray objectAtIndex:j]];  
             if(j!=0) {  
                [arrRecords removeObject:[tempArray objectAtIndex:j]];  
             }                
         }  
         [newRecords addObject:tempDict];
     }
     else {
        [newRecords addObject:[arrRecords objectAtIndex:i]];
     }  
 }
```

Comment: it's close. it goes through till [[arrRecords objectAtIndex:i] addEntriesFromDictionary:[tempArray objectAtIndex:j+1]]; and then faults: [__NSDictionaryI addEntriesFromDictionary:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x78ef0450'. is arrRecords an nsmutablearray with dictionaries? that's what I'm using.

Comment: _arrRecords_ is an _NSMutableArray_ with _NSMutableDictionary_. That's why it is crashing. I recommend you should use mutable dictionary as well. However if that's not feasible than check the edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
take one one dictionary from array and use addEntriesFromDictionary for merging them e.g.

NSMutableDictionary *dic=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"23",@"sss", nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"id",@"name", nil]];

NSMutableDictionary *dic1=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"23",@"sss", nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"id",@"animal", nil]];
if([[dic valueForKey:@"id"] isEqualToString:[dic1 valueForKey:@"id"]]){
    [dic addEntriesFromDictionary:dic1];
  }
```

Comment: Seems promising, how am I using my NSMutableArray to define dic and dic1?

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using a NSDictionary with NSArrays as the object. Then you could access the data from the array based of the id

```
NSArray* arr = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects: value, name, animal];
NSDictionary* dic = [[NSDictionary alloc]init];
[dic addObject:arr forKey:id];
```

Forgive small errors I didn't double check this against XCode, so the functions may be slightly wrong.